# How to use Typography as a styled component in react of material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I am new to the material UI. Here , I am trying to create a styled component which will be a `Typography`.  So, what I tried is ,

```
import styled from 'styled-components';


 import {
  FormGroup,
  FormControlLabel,
  Tooltip,
  FormControl,
  Select,
  Radio,
  Typography,
  Button
} from '@material-ui/core'
const StyledTypography = styled.Typography<Itest>(({ marginLeft, marginRight }) => ({
}))
```

But this gives me a compile time error.

```
Property 'Typography' does not exist on type 'ThemedStyledInterface<ThemeInterface>'
```

Can any one help me with this ?

I have used the folowing way

```
const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)<ISortBySelector>(({ fontSize }) => ({
  && {
  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  fontSize: fontSize ? fontSize : '10px',
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  fontStretch: 'normal',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  lineHeight: 'normal',
  letterSpacing: fontSize ? '0.14px' : '0.07px',
  width: fontSize ? '50px' : '35px',
  height: fontSize ? '19px' : '14px',
  color: '#000000',
  cursor: 'pointer'
  }
}))
```

Comment: yeah I have imported that you mean styled right ?

Comment: @keikai I have imported the styled but what you are saying that I am not able to understand.

Comment: @keikai I have updated the import as well please check

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if you are using the right syntax there, but this is how i usually pass components into styled-components (notice I am not using dot notation). In addition, you can use the usual CSS syntax, rather than the lower camelcased format.

```
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)<Itest>`
   && {
     font-family: Roboto;
     // customise your styles here
   }
`;
```

And if you wish to pass other props into `StyledTypography`, for instance, setting `variant` as `caption`,

```
<StyledTypography variant='caption'>
  Some text
</StyledTypography>
```

Comment: Hey thanks this works. One thing can we pass it as variant='caption' as well to that component ? Because I am trying to have that as a span so

Comment: Yes of course! You can pass props into the StyledTypography components. I have updated my example. Do let me know if it works?

Comment: Just one thing here, I have added the css for this in the styled component. But still it takes the styles of default Typography and not the one which I have specified in the style component.

Comment: Hmm... If you inspect the element using chrome devtools or something, and pick that element, what does it show? Was the css property being overwritten or something?

Comment: font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.43;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
This properties are getting overriedn

Comment: I have added the comment this are the properties which are of the body1 of typography that are getting added over here.

Comment: Its like on first render it does not get applied and when I reload the page styles gets applied

Comment: @ganeshk I understand now. Can you try adding the `&& {  }`? I have updated my example.

Comment: I have updated the way I used please check it gives me syntax  erroe

Comment: yeah I added that in the question

Comment: Ohh... You should use the normal CSS syntax. Let me give you an example on my answer

Comment: Yeah It would be great if you take my component as a example as I have used props as well there :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211266/discussion-between-wentjun-and-ganeshk).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think using dot notation is your issue. I *think* this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'

export const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)(({ theme }) => ({
  '&': {
    color: theme.palette.common.black,
    // ...and so on
  },
})) as typeof Typography
```

The other answer is ok if you're not using variables from your theme. Also, note that there's currently a bug with the `component` prop on specific components, so `as typeof Typography` might be needed.

Comment: Thanks for that! I was wondering why typescript complains about component prop...